# Is there any alternate way for Facebook Credits? or Can we use any payment gateway integration for facebook app?

Tags: payment-gateway, facebook-credits

We want to integrate payment gateway for facebook app. But we dont want to use Facebook Credits.

So is there any alternate for Facebook Credits.

or Can we use any payment gateway integration for facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no alternative. If you want to accept payments in a facebook app running on facebook.com, you must use Facebook Credits and only Facebook Credits.

If you're referring to a game, there were some workarounds in the past but they just announced [new changes](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/29/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) to the [Credits terms](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) (taking effect in December) that would tighten up those loopholes.